# more than two numbers Hexadecimal addtion

Tags: c++, hex

My code just can add two Hedecimal numbers, but we should add more than two, the input just like this FFFFFFFFFFFFF+1+2+3+4 maybe more addtion. We can use operator overloading.
That's my code.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include<cstddef>
    #include<cstring>
    using namespace std;
    int changeint(char a)
    {
    switch(a)
    {
        case '0': return 0;
        case '1': return 1;
        case '2': return 2;
        case '3': return 3;
        case '4': return 4;
        case '5': return 5;
        case '6': return 6;
        case '7': return 7;
        case '8': return 8;
        case '9': return 9;
        case 'A': return 10;
        case 'B': return 11;
        case 'C': return 12;
        case 'D': return 13;
        case 'E': return 14;
        case 'F': return 15;
    }
}

char changechar(int a)
{
    switch(a)
    {
        case 0: return '0';
        case 1: return '1';
        case 2: return '2';
        case 3: return '3';
        case 4: return '4';
        case 5: return '5';
        case 6: return '6';
        case 7: return '7';
        case 8: return '8';
        case 9: return '9';
        case 10:return 'A';
        case 11:return 'B';
        case 12:return 'C';
        case 13:return 'D';
        case 14:return 'E';
        case 15:return 'F';
    }
}

int main()
{
     string input,input_one,input_two;
    int count_one,count_two;
    cin>>input;
    count_one=input.find('+',0);
    count_two=input.length();
    input_one=input.substr(0,count_one);
    input_two=input.substr(count_one+1,count_two-count_one-1);
    char a[1000];
    char b[1000];
    char c[1001];
    a[1000]=0;
    strcpy(a,input_one.c_str());
    b[1000]=0;
    strcpy(b,input_two.c_str());
    int A[1000],B[1000],C[1001],i,lena=0,lenb=0,lenc=1000;
    for(i=0;i<1001;i++)
        C[i]=0;
    for(i=0;i<1000;i++)
    {
        A[i]=0;
        B[i]=0;
    }
    while(a[lena]!=0) lena++;
    while(b[lenb]!=0) lenb++;
    for(i=0;i<lena;i++)
        A[lena-i-1]=changeint(a[i]);
    for(i=0;i<lenb;i++)
        B[lenb-i-1]=changeint(b[i]);
    for(i=0;i<1000;i++)
    {
        C[i]=C[i]+A[i]+B[i];
        if(C[i]>15)
           {
               C[i]=C[i]-16;
               C[i+1]++;
           }
    }
    for(i=999;i>=0;i--)
    {
        if(C[i]==0) lenc--;
        else break;
    }
    if(lenc==0)
        lenc=1;
    for(i=0;i<lenc;i++)
    c[i]=changechar(C[lenc-i-1]);
    for(i=0;i<lenc;i++)
        cout<<c[i];
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can convert text digits to numbers by using `int number = a - '0';`.  No need for a switch statement.  You could also do a lookup by having an array of characters.

Comment: Thanks very much, I have rewrit it.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very convoluted program to solve a pretty trivial problem. Hint: decimal and hexadecimal is a way to represent a number, arithmetic operations will still be the same. Since you marked this question as C++, a standard library could be used. This is simple example how addition of five numbers could be achieved:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> vNumbers;
    for(int i=0; i<5; ++i)
    {
        int nNum = 0;
        std::cin >>std::hex >> nNum;
        vNumbers.push_back(nNum);
    }

    int nSum = std::accumulate(vNumbers.begin(), vNumbers.end(), 0);
    std::cout<<std::hex<<nSum<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to compose and tokenize your strings using the '+' symbol.

Then you need to convert them using inbuilt handling libraries - trying to work on this data as strings will only cause you pain!

Thirdly, I'd recommend you start again as this code looks pretty bad, sorry :0

Solve your problem conceptually on paper (considering the use of native handling of parsed hex types) then solve it in the IDE.

Good Luck!

Comment: My teacher just said I shouldn't be a programmer. I will try now. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 #include <cstdlib>
    using namespace std;
    class Hedadd
    {
    private:
        string input_string;
    public:
        void set_the_neibu(string input_the_string);
        friend Hedadd operator+(const Hedadd& string_one,const Hedadd& string_two);
        void output();
    };
    void input(string input_string,char zheng,Hedadd first_string[100],Hedadd add);
    int changeint(string a)
    {
   for (int i=0;i<100;i++)
   {
       if(a[i]=='0')
    a[i]='0';
   if(a[i]=='1')
    a[i]='1';
   if(a[i]=='2')
    a[i]='2';
if(a[i]=='3')
    a[i]='3';
if(a[i]=='4')
    a[i]='4';
if(a[i]=='5')
    a[i]='5';
if(a[i]=='6')
    a[i]='6';
if(a[i]=='7')
    a[i]='7';
if(a[i]=='8')
    a[i]='8';
if(a[i]=='9')
    a[i]='9';
if(a[i]=='A')
    a[i]='10';
if(a[i]=='B')
    a[i]='11';
if(a[i]=='C')
    a[i]='12';
if(a[i]=='D')
    a[i]='13';
if(a[i]=='E')
    a[i]='14';
if(a[i]=='F')
    a[i]='15';
    return a[i];
   }
}
string changestring(int a[100])
{
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]==0)
            a[i]=0;
        if(a[i]==1)
            a[i]=1;
         if(a[i]==2)
            a[i]=2;
             if(a[i]==3)
            a[i]=3;
             if(a[i]==4)
            a[i]=4;
             if(a[i]==5)
            a[i]=5;
             if(a[i]==6)
            a[i]=6;
            if(a[i]==7)
            a[i]=7;
             if(a[i]==8)
            a[i]=8;
             if(a[i]==9)
            a[i]=9;
            if(a[i]==10)
            a[i]='A';
             if(a[i]==11)
            a[i]='B';
             if(a[i]==12)
            a[i]='C';
             if(a[i]==13)
            a[i]='D';
             if(a[i]==14)
            a[i]='E';
             if(a[i]==15)
            a[i]='F';
    }
}

string xiangjia(string one,string two)
{
    int one_length,two_length,longer,cha,smaller,sum[1000];
    string adding_result;
    one_length=one.length();
    two_length=two.length();
    if(one_length<=two_length)
       {
           longer=two_length;
           smaller=one_length;
           cha=two_length-one_length;
           for(int i=0;i<smaller;i++)
    {
        one[i+cha]=one[i];
    }
    for(int m=0;m<cha;m++)
    {
        one[m]='0';
    }
       }
    else
        {
            longer=one_length;
            smaller=two_length;
            cha=one_length-two_length;
            for(int i=0;i<smaller;i++)
    {
        two[i+cha]=two[i];
    }
    for(int m=0;m<cha;m++)
    {
        two[m]='0';
    }
        }

            changeint(one);
            changeint(two);

    for(int i=longer;i>0;i--)
        {
            sum[i]=one[i]+two[i];
    if(sum[i]>='16')
        sum[i]=sum[i]-16;
        sum[i-1]=sum[i-1]+1;
        }
        for(int i=longer;i>0;i--)
        {
            adding_result=changestring(sum);
        }
    return (adding_result);
}
int main()
{
    string input_string;
    char zheng;
    Hedadd first_string[100],add;
    zheng='+';
    input(input_string,zheng,first_string,add);
    add.output();
    return 0;
}
void Hedadd ::set_the_neibu(string input_the_string)
{
    input_string=input_the_string;
}
void input(string input_string,char zheng,Hedadd first_string[100],Hedadd add)
{
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        if(i==0)
        {
            cin>>input_string;
            first_string[i].set_the_neibu(input_string);
            add=first_string[i];
        }
        if(i!=0)
        {
            cin>>zheng>>input_string;
            first_string[i].set_the_neibu(input_string);
            add=add+first_string[i];
        }
    }
}
Hedadd operator+(const Hedadd& string_one,const Hedadd& string_two)
{
    Hedadd string_together;
    string_together.input_string=xiangjia(string_one.input_string,string_two.input_string);
    return(string_together);
}
void Hedadd::output()
{
    cout<<input_string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
class Hedadd
{
private:
    string input_string;
public:
    void set_the_neibu(string input_the_string);
    friend Hedadd operator+(const Hedadd& string_one, const Hedadd& string_two);
    void output();
};
Hedadd input(string input_string, char zheng, Hedadd first_string, Hedadd add);
void changeint(char a[100],int b[100])
{
    for (int i = 0; i<100; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] <= '9'&&a[i]>='0')
            b[i] = a[i] - '0';
        else
            b[i] = a[i] - 'A' + 10;
    }

}
string changestring(int a[100])
{
    char b[101];
    for (int i = 0; i<100; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] <= 9&&a[i] >= 0)
            b[i] = a[i] + '0';
        else
            b[i] = a[i] + 'A' - 10;
    }
    b[100] = '\0';
    return string(b);

}

string xiangjia(string one, string two)
{
    int one_length, two_length, longer, cha, smaller, sum[100];
    char c_one[100];
    char c_two[100];
    int int_one[100];
    int int_two[100];
    string adding_result;
    one_length = one.length();
    two_length = two.length();
    longer = one_length > two_length ? one_length : two_length;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        c_one[i] = '0';
        c_two[i] = '0';
        sum[i] = 0;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= one_length; i++)
    {
        c_one[100 - i] = one.c_str()[one_length - i];
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= two_length; i++)
    {
        c_two[100 - i] = two.c_str()[two_length - i];
    }



    changeint(c_one,int_one);
    changeint(c_two,int_two);

    for (int i = 1; i<=longer; i++)
    {
        sum[100 - i] += int_one[100 - i] +int_two[100 - i];
        if (sum[100 - i] >= 16)
        {
            sum[100 - i] = sum[100 - i] - 16;
            sum[100 - i - 1] = sum[100 - i - 1] + 1;
        }
    }
    adding_result = changestring(sum);
    int count = 0;
    for (count = 0; count < 100; count++)
    {
        if (sum[count]!=0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return (adding_result.substr(count,adding_result.length() - count));
}
int main()
{
    string input_string;
    char zheng;
    Hedadd first_string, add;
    zheng = '+';
    add = input(input_string, zheng, first_string, add);
    add.output();
    return 0;
}
void Hedadd::set_the_neibu(string input_the_string)
{
    input_string = input_the_string;
}
Hedadd input(string input_string, char zheng, Hedadd first_string, Hedadd add)
{
    string temp = "";
    cin >> temp;
    add.set_the_neibu("0");
    int offset = temp.find_first_of('+');
    while (offset != std::string::npos)
    {
        first_string.set_the_neibu(temp.substr(0,offset));
        add = add + first_string;
        temp = temp.substr(offset+1, temp.length() - offset-1);
        offset = temp.find_first_of('+');
    }
    first_string.set_the_neibu(temp.substr(0, offset));
    add = add + first_string;
    return add;
}
Hedadd operator+(const Hedadd& string_one, const Hedadd& string_two)
{
    Hedadd string_together;
    string_together.input_string = xiangjia(string_one.input_string, string_two.input_string);
    return(string_together);
}
void Hedadd::output()
{
    cout << input_string;
}

    enter code here
```